# How do I theme a taxonomy term page?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, theming

I am working on Drupal 8, trying to get a page template for each vocabulary. I have tried using `hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter()` to achieve this, but I was not able to do it.

I tried using Devel with `kint()`, but no debugging information is shown on my screen.

How can I add a template suggestion for a vocabulary?

Answer (score 16):

You can suggest a new template file with the following code.

**Drupal 8**

```
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;

function THEME_NAME_theme_suggestions_page_alter(&$suggestions, &$vars) {
  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'entity.taxonomy_term.canonical' && $tid = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('taxonomy_term')) {
    $term = Term::load($tid);
    $suggestions[] = 'page__taxonomy__' . $term->getVocabularyId();
  }
}
```

**Drupal 9**

```
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;

function THEME_NAME_theme_suggestions_page_alter(&$suggestions, &$vars) {
  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'entity.taxonomy_term.canonical' && $tid = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('taxonomy_term')) {
    $term = Term::load($tid);
    $suggestions[] = 'page__taxonomy__' . $term->bundle();
  }
}
```

Then create the file: `page--taxonomy--VOCABULARYNAME.html.twig` and customise it as you wish.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you please also tell me how do I print the term name in this template?

Comment: @SaeedAfzal try using {{ name }}

Comment: ℹ️I've got the Taxonomy Term view that comes with Drupal core enabled, therefore   `Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName()` is returning `view.taxonomy_term.page_1`. HTH.

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 9, the `getVocabularyId()` method [is deprecated](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21src%21TermInterface.php/function/TermInterface%3A%3AgetVocabularyId/8.9.x) so we use `bundle()` instead.

Use this hook in Drupal 9:

```
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;

/*
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter()
 */

function THEMENAME_theme_suggestions_page_alter(&$suggestions, &$vars) {
  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'entity.taxonomy_term.canonical' && $tid = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('taxonomy_term')) {
    $term = Term::load($tid);
    $suggestions[] = 'page__taxonomy__' . $term->bundle();
  }
}
```