# How to make page.html.twig based on Vocabulary?

Tags: 8, theming

I want to make different page.html.twig according to different Vocabulary.
 I found this code:

```
function THEME_NAME_theme_suggestions_page_alter(&$suggestions, &$vars) {
  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'entity.taxonomy_term.canonical' && $tid = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('taxonomy_term')) {
    $term = Term::load($tid);
    $suggestions[] = 'page__taxonomy__' . $term->getVocabularyId();
  }
}
```

in [How do I theme a taxonomy term page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207243/how-do-i-theme-a-taxonomy-term-page).
Code does not work:

> Fatal error: Class 'Term' not found in...

Excuse me, what is the reason, I really need to customize the page.html.twig according to the vocabulary, you can help me？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have not included the PHP code that contains the Class.

See [Namespacing in PHP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aB1VRlQmq1M).

According to [term.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!taxonomy!src!Entity!Term.php/8.2.x) the name space is `Drupal\taxonomy\Entity`.

So you need to add `use [name space]\[class name];` at the top.

Therefore, it would be `use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;`.

**Example:**

```
<?php

use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;

function THEME_NAME_theme_suggestions_page_alter(&$suggestions, &$vars) {
  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'entity.taxonomy_term.canonical' && $tid = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('taxonomy_term')) {
    $term = Term::load($tid);
    $suggestions[] = 'page__taxonomy__' . $term->getVocabularyId();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, you are a good person, but still do not understand, can not directly code, thank you very much!

Comment: @LIUJIAHUI Did you get it to work? If not working, did you get any errors? or ???

Comment: No Sssweat，The problem is solved, thank you very much！

Comment: Very sorry, I was the first time to submit a question, I do not know where to choose...

Comment: Don't sweat it, welcome to Drupal Answers `:)`

Comment: For Drupal 9 you should to replace `$term->getVocabularyId()` for `$term->bundle()`