# Adding taxonomy term as class

Tags: 8, theming, entities

I'd like to add a taxonomy term to the list of CSS classes for a div with the id "primary" on a modified Bartik theme. I know the change needs to happen at page.html.twig or something derived from that, but I'm having a hard time determining how the preprocess page and the twig function together.

Based on this example: [How do I theme a taxonomy term page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207243/how-do-i-theme-a-taxonomy-term-page)

I've added the following information to a theme file:

```
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;

function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_page_alter(&$suggestions, &$vars) {
  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'entity.taxonomy_term.canonical'$
    $term = Term::load($tid);
    $suggestions[] = 'page__taxonomy__' . $term->getVocabularyId();
  }
}
```

And added a new twig called page--taxonomy--TAXONOMYTERM.html.twig where I added "taxonomy-TAXONOMYTERM" as a class to the div I'm looking to alter:

```
 <div id="primary" class="{{'taxonomy-TAXONOMYTERM ' ~ 'content-area col-sm-' ~ primary_col }}">
```

As far as I can tell, according to the example this should work. But in reality, the term isn't showing up when I look at an article with the appropirate taxonomy term.  What am I doing wrong?  Is there a better way to attach the taxonomy term to a div class?

Thanks!

Comment: Where does this div live?

Comment: Also I don't think you need to make an entirely new page twig template for this - just create the class in a preprocess and pass it along. It used to be called `body_classes` but im not sure what it is called now at the moment.

Comment: It lives on both pages and articles -- basically anything that is processed through page.html.twig.